# Constructor call hierarchy

Tags: c++, constructor, call, hierarchy

I'm having a tricky time with calling rules for constructors in a type hierarchy. Here is what I do:

```
class A{
protected:
    int _i;
public:
    A(){i = 0;}
    A(int i) : _i(i){}
    virtual ~A(){}
    virtual void print(){std::cout<<i<<std::endl;}
};

class B : virtual public A{
protected:
    int _j;
public:
    B() : A(){_j = 0;}
    B(int i, int j) : A(i), _j(j){}
    virtual ~B(){}
    virtual void print(){std::cout<<i<<", "<<j<<std::endl;}
};

class C : virtual public B{
protected:
    int _k;
public:
    C() : B(){_k = 0;}
    C(int i, int j, int k} : B(i,j), _k(k){}
    virtual ~C(){}
    virtual void print(){std::cout<<i<<", "<<j<<", "<<k<<std::endl;}
};

int main(){
    C* myC = new C(1,2,3);
    myC->print();
    delete myC;
    return 0;
}
```

Now, I would like to have new C(1,2,3) call the constructor of B(1,2) which then in turn should call the constructor A(1) to store _i=1, _j=2, _k=3. When creating the instance myC of the class C, for some reason I don't understand, however, the first constructor to be called is the standard constructor of A, i.e., A::A(); This obviously leads to wrong results, as the protected variable _i is assigned the value 0. The constructor A(1) is never called. Why is this so? I find this very counter intuitive. Is there some way to avoid explicitly calling all constructors within the type-hierarchy to achieve the desired behavior?

Thx for the help!

Comment: Thx for the kind answers. So, I guess I'll go back to Stroustrup to re-read the concept of virtual inheritance. Seems it is not wise to use it by default ;)

Comment: Many people wonder why inheritance is not virtual by default. Well, you've found the answer by yourself :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use virtual inheritance, the most derived class must call the constructors for all its virtual bases directly. In this case, the constructor for `C` must call the constructors for `B` and `A`. Since you only call the `B` constructor, it uses the default `A` constructor. It does not matter that the `B` constructor calls another `A` constructor: since it is a virtual base class, this call is ignored.

You have two ways around this problem: explicitly call the `A(int)` constructor:

```
C(int i, int j, int k} : A (i), B(i,j), _k(k){}
```

or use normal inheritance instead of virtual.

Comment: The most derived class doesn't _have_ to explicitly call the constructors for its virtual base classes, it can let them be implicitly default initialized as in the question. However it does it, though, you are correct that it is always the most derived class that initialized the virtual bases.

Comment: @CharlesBailey Rereading my answer, you are right: I did not explain that correctly (that *explicitly* is misleading). I am fixing it.

Answer (score 7):

do you really need a `virtual` inheritance here?
you've got a problem because a very first virtual base ctor will be called first, but you don't specify any when inherit `C` from `B` (latter already have `A` virtually inherited, so default was called).

one solution is to remove virtual inheritance... as mentioned in the answer of Arne Mertz.
another (if you really want virtual inheritance) is to call `A` explicitly from `C` ctor:

```
C(int i, int j, int k} : A(i), B(i,j), _k(k){}
```

Answer (score 6):

This is because you used virtual inheritance, which makes only sense in the presence of multiple inheritances. Just inherit normally, and all will be as you expect it.

Comment: If `A` is an interface, and `B` extends that interface, then virtual inheritance is really the only correct solution.  (Of course, if `A` is an interface, it won't have any data members, and so no user defined constructors.  Generally, virtual inheritance is only applicable for interfaces.)

Comment: @JamesKanze, it's wrong, you don't need virtual inheritance if you are not doing multiple inheritance from 2+ classes having common ancestor. Furthermore, you can implement multiple interfaces without virtual inheritance: see COM for example.

Comment: I think I don't get your definition of "interface". Do you mean the Java kind of interface (i.e. an abstract class without members)? However, I've seen lots of different kinds of things in C++ one could call an itnerface, but none of them needed virtual inheritance. Of course, in certain circumstances abstract classes might get entangled in multiple inheritance graphs, but since they have no members, shouldn't the vtables just work, even without virtual inheritance?

Comment: @Steed When extending an interface, you can't know whether there will be other extensions, nor whether some concrete class will want to implement two or more of the extensions.  So you have to inherit virtually (unless you're dealing with a small, closed hierarchy, where you can easily return and add the virtual inheritance when it becomes necessary).

Comment: @ArneMertz More or less.  It's a frequent pattern in C++, as well as in Java (except that it works in C++---you're virtual functions can still be private, with non-virtual wrappers to check pre- and post-conditions).  _If_ you extend an interface (with another interface), then you should generally inherit virtually.

Comment: @ArneMertz And even if the classes have no members, `Base* pb = new Derived;` is ambiguous if there is more than one instance of `Base` in the hierarchy.

Comment: @JamesKanze, we are not going to start a pro and contra virtual ineritance discussion, are we? It has it advantages and drawbacks. My point is that it's not the only and not always the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you declare virtual inheritance? If you remove virtual keyword from class B: virtual public A { ... then your code will work fine. By declaring virtual A, C will call A() directly. If you remove virtual then C will not call A().